# Accessing specific nodes JSON

Tags: python, json

This is my JSON

```
{"sites":[{"site_id":1234,..,..}, {"site_id":5678,..,..}]}
```

I'm trying to loop through it using:

```
for site_id in account['sites']['site_id']:
    print(site_id)
```

Which yields:

```
list indices must be integers, not str
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`account['sites']` is a list of dictionaries, iterate over it and get the value by `site_id` key:

```
for site in account['sites']:
    print site['site_id']
```

Comment: I can swear I did that but got an error.. now it works. I'll mark this as answer as soon as I can.